# .htaccess 301 redirect issue with OpenCart

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart, redirect

I'm having issues with redirecting my OpenCart website from non-www to a www version.

I've tried a few solutions from other people's posts, but they all seem to not work on my site.

My .htaccess file currently looks like this:

```
# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place this rule at the top of your rule list, Below rewrite Base

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found [DevZer0's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480683) helpful.

However, I *also* had to edit my `config.php` file in both the `public_html` and the `admin` folder to change my site url from the non-www to the www version.  Without this change, the "add to cart" feature never worked.